# launch an activity in different task

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to launch an activity (say abc) in a different task every time I launch the activity with flag_new_task.

How do i set a different affinity to the activity each time I launch it.

thanks,

Comment: See a very good EXPLANATION: https://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set both the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching the activity, then Android will create a new task every time you do it.

**BIG WARNING**

HOWEVER, if you create many tasks like this using the same activity, there is no way for the user to return to a specific task by long-pressing on the HOME button. You need to make sure that you don't confuse the user when you do this.

See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

Comment: Hi David, Can I switch between these tasks programatically

Comment: I don't think so. This isn't really a good model for Android programming. Can you explain why you want to do this? There is probably a different/better approach available.

Comment: From a service I want to create different task stack for every request I recieve through service. For every user app accessing the service, there will be separate task stack. Now, within service I would like to  manage different task stacks invoked

Comment: You may be able to manage this programmatically by using `ActivityManager`. There are methods like `moveTaskToFront()` and `getRunningTasks()` that you can use. I still don't understand why you would want to do this, though. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks david ... but moveTaskToFront() is only available after api 11 ... Can I achieve the same functionality prior to api 11 ?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of. You may be able to access some private API fdr this, but I would have to dig through the source code to figure that out.